# Texto de Una Columna concreta de una GridView

Tags: c#, gridview

¿Como puedo obtener el texto de una `cell` de una `column` concreta en una `GridView`?

Necesito el texto de una `celda` en concreto, modificarlo, y volver a meterlo en la misma celda, pero no se como acceder al `Text` de cada una de las `Cells` de la `column` del `GridView` y asi luego modificar los textos.

Answer (score 2):

Siendo `dataGridView` el `(Name)` de tu `DataGridView` sería algo así:

```
String texto = dataGridView.Rows[numeroFila].Cells[numeroColumna].Value.ToString();
```

Comment: Graciaaas probare con eso

Answer (score 2):

Este es el modo corto de la respuesta de @cnbandicoot

Obtener el valor de una celda:

```
string valor = dataGridView[colIndex, rowIndex].Value.ToString();
```

Para establecer valor de una celda:

```
dataGridView[colIndex, rowIndex].Value = valor;
```